# IntelliJ Gradle project option not showing when creating new project

Tags: gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea

I am trying setting up a Kotlin/JS for Browser project, but when I open the "New Project"-Window, Gradle Projects are not an option.

[image: New Project]

Everywhere I search, it just seems to be there. Also, I wasnt able to find any kind of solution or even mention of the problem.

[image: Example from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-project-setup.html]

(This is from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-project-setup.html how it should look like)

For sure I am just really, really stupid overseeing the most simple thing missing. But as I keep failing, does anybody know how I can include the option for Gradle Projects? Your help would be much appreciated!

-----------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------

I reinstalled IntelliJ IDEA and now it is working just fine. I don't know what was the problem, maybe an update went wrong or something. Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: Please specify the version of the IDE you're currently using. Do you have the necessary plugins installed and enabled?

Comment: @ysakhno My version is 2019.3.3. Gradle-Plugin was pre-installed and is activated (double-checked a lot of times on that...) I have TornadoFX and one of the Default-Projects has gradle in it. Works fine. Just creating a Gradle Project is not possible, as it is not shown

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem with IDEA 2020.2 on Linux.  My New Project window looked just like the OP's.  Reinstall didn't fix, but I got the Gradle option to appear by enabling the bundled Android plugin.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have **Gradle** bundled [plugin enabled](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.2/managing-plugins.html). Make sure you have it enabled in Settings | Plugins. Another indication that it is enabled is the Settings(Preferences) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | **Gradle** page.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2 There is a disabled_plugins.txt, open it and delete the "org.gradle..." things and save it. Restart IntelliJ. It helped me, there are Gradle options in New Projects window.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue on intellij 2021.3.2 after enabling the gradle plugin that I had kept disabled. It started showing up for me after enabling the bundled Android plugin.